# How to Efficiently Farm Top / Mid Lane?

Tags: league-of-legends

I noticed that I often have less farm than my lane opponent. At around 20 minutes, I'll have 80-100 CS.

My problem is not last hitting; I am familiar with the concept and I think I actually do it well.

Although that seems to be exactly my problem: when I strictly last hit, my lane gets pushed by the enemy (because he/she tends to kill more). Sooner or later my tower will steal some CS.

Are there any guides / concepts about how to farm efficiently in top/mid lane?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Getting CS is about much more than just last hitting. In fact, solo laning itself revolves almost strictly around last hitting in high level play. You need to know how to balance all of the following:

**Last Hitting**: the skill of knowing how much damage you do to a minion to ensure that you obtain the gold from killing it.

**Keeping the lane where you want it**: This is a huge factor, some champions like Malzahar and Morganna can push harder than champions like Ryze because of their AoE abilities so should the Ryze player wish to keep the lane in the middle he must attack the wave more than just when the last hit is available.

Some champions however excel at killing minions under their own tower and may want to keep the lane there for safety while others have many escapes and can push to the enemy tower all they want and still escape back to their own should the enemy jungler gank. Part of mastering your favorite champions is learning how to balance risk vs reward with your available tool set.

**Harassing**: You also might not want to only keep an eye on the health bars of the enemy minions, you should also keep an eye on your own. This is especially important in top lane where the enemy usually last hits in melee range. Therefore you know where the enemy will need to be in order to get that gold. If you move or attack in such a way that they cannot reach that low hp minion without taking significant damage they will miss the gold or better. The #1 rule of hunting is: attack your prey when it attacks it's own.

**Counters**: Most champions have a wide array of other champions that they do particularly well against. Counters usually are formed when a champion excels in one of the above areas that their opponent lacks.

Comment: "Some champions however excel at killing minions under their own tower " - could you give an example? (I'm relatively new to the game, and I frequently struggle racing against the tower when I'm pushed back to it.)

Comment: Well if you don't have any great Spells to kill the minions under your tower, you have to do it like this:

- Ranged minions -> Hit them once - let the Tower hit them once, then kill them

- Melee minions -> Let the tower hit them twice then kill them

Comment: Annie and Ryze are decent examples. Annie can use her Q to last hit pretty well and Ryze has some very spammable spells with blue buff. Any champions with big AoE nukes are also effective like Ahri.

@Toby That doesn't quite work for casters in mid lane because they don't have the attack to last hit like that after a couple minutes. For example around level 3 if I'm mid with a caster I need to hit the ranged minion once before the tower, then again after it to secure the last hit.

Comment: Would give +2 if possible, great answer!

Answer (score 2):

With top lane I always tend to get a wriggles, which will help you CS and sustain.

Also, coordinate with your jungle to pick up wolves or wraiths (as well as ganks).

Teleport can help you get CS if you are losing CS from being gone.

Promote is also underrated; you get the gold from the minions your promoted unit kills.

Another tactic is getting a Philo Stone, etc. to make up the difference.

I think the other answers to this question are better, but these are a few more strategies.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to balance just last hitting with auto-attack pushing. You don't want to fight under their tower, but unless your hero of choice has enough burst to be able to still last hit under your tower, you don't want to be there either. Just last hit until your 1 wave away from being pushed under your tower, then auto-attack for 1 wave to push back into lane. Rinse, Repeat.

Answer (score 0):

If your opponent is clearing waves faster than you and pushing them into your turret, you need to dish out more damage to compensate.

Ex: Mordekaiser has an amazing ability to push minion waves.  Instead of only last-hitting, it's important to clear as much of the wave as possible before it gets to your tower.

The principle of last-hitting is to avoid pushing your lane.  When both players do this, the lane stays roughly in the middle.  If one champion is actively pushing their lane, last-hitting leads to missed CS.

Answer (score 0):

just go to pratice. pick an AP without AD runes and try to farm just with basic attack. I used to have 100 minions at 15min. The aim is 100cs in 10min. so, you just need to practice